# Why thymeleaf messages showing incorrectly?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

1.I have defined the i18n files location.

```
spring.messages.basename=i18n/messages
```

2.There exists files for messages and keys for `login.rememberMe`.

i18n/messages_zh_CN.properties

```
login.rememberMe=记住我
```

i18n/messages_en_US.properties

```
login.rememberMe=Remember Me
```

3.This is the message content for Login.html.

```
<label th:text="#{login.rememberMe}"></label>
```

The page showing `??login.rememberMe_zh_CN??` and I didn't find the issue.

[image]

Comment: Does the property exist? Why is it prefaced with "lib"?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, it does exists, it's Intellij Idea's feature that messages with `lib`.

Comment: Images of code are useless here. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons why. Code is text, and can be copied/pasted directly into your post and properly formatted as code. Images should be kept to an absolute minimum, and only used when a problem cannot be demonstrated without it.

Comment: @KenWhite I have updated my post, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that Spring boot's [`MessageSourceAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/context/MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.java) only kicks in when the [`ResourceBundleCondition`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/de47827eb4ee442ea7f6191131722d3abdab776e/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/context/MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.java#L148) condition is met. The most [important line](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/context/MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.java#L184) here is:

```
return new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(classLoader)
                    .getResources("classpath*:" + name + ".properties");
```

This basically means that your `MessageSource` is only created when there's a file called `classpath:i18n/messages.properties`, which is the default resourcebundle if none of the locales match.

---

My guess is that you only have a `messages_en_US.properties` and a `messages_zh_CN.properties`. This means that in order to solve it, you need to create a default `messages.properties` file.

You can either choose to create a blank `messages.properties` file, or decide if your **en-US** or **zh-CN** locale is your default, and rename either one of them to `messages.properties`.

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to create a default resourcebundle, you can also create your own `MessageSource`:

```java
@Bean
public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    source.setBasenames("i18n/messages");
    source.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    return source;
}
```

Comment: Actually, set this: `spring.messages.fallbackToSystemLocale: false`,defaulted true will be as system locale.